# Determine the sender from Multiple Accessory Buttons in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Right now I have a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell that contains 2 accessory buttons.

When one of the buttons is tapped it triggers either:

```
(void) shareButtonTapped:(UIControl *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
   NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:[[[event touchesForView: button] anyObject] locationInView: self.tableview]];
    if ( indexPath == nil )
        return;

    [self.tableview.delegate tableView:self.tableview accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

or

```
(IBAction)callButtonTapped:(UIControl *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:[[[event touchesForView: button] anyObject] locationInView: self.tableview]];
    if ( indexPath == nil )
        return;

    [self.tableview.delegate tableView:self.tableview accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

I then use the following method to handle the touch event.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        NSLog(@"Accessory tapped for row %d", indexPath.row);
}
```

My question: In "accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath" how can I figure out which of the two buttons were pressed in the UITableViewCell? I would like to handle each touch differently.

Comment: why do you eventually call *accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath*, why not call a custom method of yours?

Comment: I thought that was best practice...assumed that was how buttons were supposed to be handled within UITableViewCells. Am I incorrect here? I will need the index of the button pressed as well as the type of button pressed

Comment: As far as I know, since you are not using an accessory button, this method doesn't need to be called. You can implement your own event handler method.

Comment: Wouldn't it be considered an accessory button if it displays on each row (ie each UITableViewCell?). I'll try and call my own method

Comment: No, this is not an accessory button, an accessory button is when you set the [accessoryType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryType) property of a tableViewCell and you can never have 2 on the same cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mariam pointed out, I am using my own custom method to receive the call rather than the built in accessoryBUttonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method.